# How to get from JFK to Brooklyn NY 11217, USA by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, new-york-city, jfk

I have to get from the JFK airport to Brooklyn NY 11217, USA on a Wednesday afternoon by public transport. What are the fastest and cheapest options using public transport?

I need to go back the whole way 5 days later, so if a travel pass is cheaper, that would also be an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Fastest**

1. [JFK AirTrain](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/jfk-airtrain.html) to Jamaica Station ($5, ~15 min)
2. Inbound [Long Island Rail Road](http://www.mta.info/lirr/) service to [Atlantic Terminal](http://lirr42.mta.info/stationInfo.php?id=12) ($6.25, ~20 min)

**Cheapest**

1. [JFK AirTrain](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/jfk-airtrain.html) to Howard Beach Station ($5, ~15 min)
2. [A Train](http://mta.info/nyct/service/aline.htm) (NYC Subway) to Hoyt-Schermerhorn Station ($2.25, ~30 min)

Well, that's not entirely true. The *truly* cheapest options are to take the B15 bus and transfer to another bus somewhere in east Brooklyn, or to take the Q10 bus to Lefferts Blvd-Ozone Park Station and take the A Train from there to Hoy-Schermerhorn. Either ride would be $2.25 for the whole trip with a MetroCard. These are a much, much longer routes (up to two hours) through some very, very boring areas, and I would not advise a visitor, who has limited time, to bother with them.

If you want to play with some options yourself, try the [MTA Trip Planner](http://tripplanner.mta.info/).

I'm not familiar with the MTA pass options, but you can save money by buying multi-trip MetroCards. MTA has a handy [guide to MetroCard options](http://www.mta.info/mta/fares/mc_value.htm) based on the number of rides.